# How do i display the attributes of a thread in C?

Tags: c, pthreads

Since `pthread_t` is a struct, I thought that I could simply get the attributes directly. Checked this page and saw the names of the thread attributes (detachedstate, schedparam etc) so I tried it like this:

```
pthread_t t1;

void routine() {
    printf(t1.inheritsched);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {    
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &routine, NULL);
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

But i got an error saying basically that `pthread_t` isn’t a struct, which surprised me.

What exactly is going on, and how can i display a thread's attributes?

Comment: Re "*Since `pthread_t` is a struct,*", It's `typedef unsigned long int pthread_t;` on my Linux box, and it's apparently something similar on yours.

Comment: *Since `pthread_t` is a struct* No it's not.  In fact [prior to POSIX 6 is was **required** to be an arithmetic type](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/sys_types.h.html#tag_13_65_10):  "... adding `pthread_t` to the list of types that are not required to be arithmetic types ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specification says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html):

> Upon successful completion, `pthread_create()` shall store the ID of the created thread in the location referenced by `thread`.

Thus we know that `pthread_t` is just the ID of the thread, with the exact type [not stated in the specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html).